# Why is there an output ripple on my LM2576?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, buck, ringing

I built a buck converter using the [LM2576HVT-15/NOPB](https://www.ti.com/product/LM2576HV/part-details/LM2576HVT-15/NOPB?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=ocb-tistore-promo-app_opn_en-cpc-storeic-google-wwe&utm_content=Device&ds_k=LM2576HVT-15/NOPB&DCM=yes&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8KWGwdTAgAMVEkhHAR3ojAIOEAAYASAAEgIasvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds). I built it exactly like the recommended schematic:

[image]

The diode I am using is a [1N5822](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/d8/3f/72/85/bc/90/4e/f7/CD00001626.pdf/files/CD00001626.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00001626.pdf) and the inductor is a [470uH inductor](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/signal-transformer/HCTI-470-3-8/7362987) with a 100uF electrolytic capacitor and a 1000uF electrolytic capacitor. I created this circuit on a breadboard. When I use a load that pulls about .75A - 1A, the buck converter seems to work great. But when I use it to power 3 [IR2110PBF](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IR2110-DataSheet-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c80333167e&redirId=119801) IC's (which is what my design needs it for) it has a lot of ringing on the output pin before it reaches the inductor as seen in the image below:

[image]

While there is a lot of ringing on the output pin, after it goes through the inductor and is smoothed by the 1000 uF capacitor the voltage is pretty constant at 15V with about a 0.5V ripple which is what I want to happen, so perhaps this isn't a problem I need to worry about?

I am curious why is it ringing so much on the output? Is it the layout of my design because it is on a breadboard? Do I need to select a lower value inductor? Why is there no ringing when the load pulls 0.75A - 1A?

Comment: No harm done : ) it is just the buck converter transitioning into the discontinuous conduction mode or DCM. In continuous conduction mode (CCM), the inductor current never cancels within a switching period. When the load current gets lighter, the *average* inductor reduces and, at some point, the *valley* current (the minimum inductor current) hits zero and the diode spontaneously blocks. The switch/diode junction parasitic capacitance forms a resonant network with the inductor and a decaying oscillation takes place until the power switch is turned back on.